# How do I statements for the various conditions of this function?

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, arduino-ide

I am still new to Aduino and I am trying to use a library's example sketch but I don't understand the following part of the code. I want to trigger an led when the "Pressed" condition is fulfilled. Pardon my ignorance.

```
if (b != ClickEncoder::Open) {
Serial.print("Button: ");
#define VERBOSECASE(label) case label: Serial.println(#label); break;
switch (b) {
  VERBOSECASE(ClickEncoder::Pressed);
  VERBOSECASE(ClickEncoder::Held)
  VERBOSECASE(ClickEncoder::Released)
  VERBOSECASE(ClickEncoder::Clicked)

  case ClickEncoder::DoubleClicked:
      Serial.println("ClickEncoder::DoubleClicked");
      encoder->setAccelerationEnabled(!encoder->getAccelerationEnabled());
      Serial.print("  Acceleration is ");
      Serial.println((encoder->getAccelerationEnabled()) ? "enabled" : "disabled");
      setMode = true;
       value = 0;
    break;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm no expert either, but I think this is just Displaying the status of the button out to the Serial port, whether it's been Pressed, Held, Released etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to explicitely expand the case `ClickEncoder::Pressed`. So instead of

```
VERBOSECASE(ClickEncoder::Pressed);
```

you should write something like

```
case ClickEncoder::Pressed:
    Serial.println("ClickEncoder::Pressed");
    digitalWrite(ledpin, HIGH);
    break;
```

Of course then you'll have to turn it off then, but.. Well, that's another problem